# I can't print my node.js console.log into my HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browser, arduino

I am currently working on a project where I am trying to send a serial print from a microcontroller to a website. I have made a node.js server that works and prints the desired value, but when I try to send this to a html document I get the error code: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined".

here is my code:

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Node.js to html code</h1>
<p>Message:</p>

<p id="message"></p>


<script src="app.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

var SerialPort = require('serialport');
const parsers = SerialPort.parsers;

const parser = new parsers.Readline({
  delimiter: '\r\n',
});

var port = new SerialPort('COM6', {
  baudRate: 9600,
  dataBits: 8,
  parity: 'none',
  stopBits: 1,
  flowControl: false,
});

port.pipe(parser);

var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
  res.end(index);
});

var io = require('socket.io')(app);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('Node is listening to port');
});

parser.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Received data from port: ' + data);
  io.emit('data', data);
  socket.emit('message',data);
});
```

I have tried to import this function as it is not defined by default in chrome. I have also tried to set my JSON package as "type": "module", but this has not resolved the issue either.

Comment: Even if you get `require` working in a web browser, the code you are trying to run cannot be run from a browser. Web browsers are not allowed to read files from your local disk (with `fs.readFileSync` for example) - think about the horrible security implication if this were true. Any website you visit could just read any file from your local disk.  What you will likely need to do is run your code as a Node server, and then either have it render an HTML page you view, or have your HTML get the data via an API request.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running into is that (for good* reason) browsers limit direct access to the users system. Assuming that your goal is **to display the serialport data in a webpage**, there are some "simple" solutions.

### Solution 1

Your node server receives and stores the serialport messages and embeds these into the html when serving. This way you can see the most up to date version of the serial messages *every time you refresh the page*

- Remove the `<script>`-tag from your index.html
- Set a placeholder like `##SERIALMESSAGES##`
- Store all received messages in a string by appending them
- When serving index.html replace the placeholder with the messages

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Node.js to html code</h1>
<p>Message:</p>

<p id="message">
  ##SERIALMESSAGES##
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
var serialMessages = ""

var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });

  // put the messages into index.html before serving it to the client
  const indexWithMessages = index.replace("##SERIALMESSAGES##", serialMessages)

  res.end(indexWithMessages);
});

parser.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Received data from port: ' + data);

  // append the received data
  serialMessages += data + "\n"

  io.emit('data', data);
  socket.emit('message',data);
});
```

### Solution 2

A more complex, but in my opinion more fitting way to do this is to use [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)

With this approach you would have two js files, one for node (server.js) to run as a backend and a second that is ran in the browser (client.js). server.js will listen to the serialport and serve index.html when requested (just like now). index.html will use client.js, which connects and listens to the websocket. Whenever the websocket recieves a message it can then append that to your `<p>` innerHtml to 'live' display new messages.

Now backend.js needs to also start a websocket server to which the client.js can connect and then all messages received on the serialport can be relayed to the websocket which the client.js (and therefor the browser) can recieve and display.

If you have any questions be sure to let me know. I'd be happy to provide any further assistance!

Comment: Upvote for Solution 2,  that's the proper way to go.